# Unable to position buttons to bottom of flex container (when importing to WordPress)

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox

I'm fairly new to Flexbox but I've managed to create a basic pricing table.  One of the key things I wan to achieve is having the 'Sign-up' buttons (that appear in each column) positioned at the bottom of the column / flex container.

My HTML and CSS works perfectly locally (testing in Chrome) however I want to import this into WordPress (simply via the child theme CSS and dropping the HTML into the editor of the relevant page).  When I do this, everything works fine with the exception of the button positioning.  The buttons are no longer getting positioned at the bottom of the container.

When I inspect the wordpress code using dev tools, the 'margin-top: auto' CSS declaration appears to be present so I can't work out why it is not being applied.

Here is my HTML & relevant flexbox related CSS:

```
<div class="p_columns">
    <div class="p_price p_bdr_1">
        <ul class="p_ul">
            <li class="p_header">Free</li>
            <li class="p_sub_header">Basic</li>
            <li class="p_li">Limited support</li>
            <li class="p_li">Lots of Storage</li>
            <li class="p_li">High speed bandwidth</li>
            <li class="p_li">Premium design</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="p_btn">Activate</a>

    </div>
    <div class="p_price p_bdr_2">
        <ul class="p_ul">
            <li class="p_header">Free</li>
            <li class="p_sub_header">Basic</li>
            <li class="p_li">Limited support</li>
            <li class="p_li">Lots of Storage</li>
            <li class="p_li">High speed bandwidth</li>
            <li class="p_li">Premium design</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="p_btn">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
    <div class="p_price p_bdr_3">
        <ul class="p_ul">
            <li class="p_header">Free</li>
            <li class="p_sub_header">Basic</li>
            <li class="p_li">Limited support</li>
            <li class="p_li">Lots of Storage</li>
            <li class="p_li">High speed bandwidth</li>
            <li class="p_li">Premium design</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="p_btn">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
    <div class="p_price p_bdr_4">
        <ul class="p_ul">
            <li class="p_header">Free</li>
            <li class="p_sub_header">Basic</li>
            <li class="p_li">Limited support</li>
            <li class="p_li">Lots of Storage</li>
            <li class="p_li">High speed bandwidth</li>
            <li class="p_li">Premium design</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="p_btn">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
</div>

.p_columns {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
max-width: 85%;
min-height: 700px;
}

.p_price {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 200px;
    flex-flow: column;
}

.p_btn {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks, Todd

Comment: There may be rules from the parent theme which are effecting the behavior of your own CSS rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add:

```
.p_price {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 200px;
    flex-flow: column;
    position:relative;
}
.p_price p {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

For also centering the button, use this code snippet:

```
.p_price {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 200px;
    flex-flow: column;
    position:relative;
}
.p_price p {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly!  Most appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

Your `a.p_btn` tags are being wrapped in `p` tags - if you remove these it restores your desired layout.

Wordpress will automatically convert double line-breaks to paragraph tags. It may be worth disabling the automatic paragraph filter `wpautop` as described at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter

Comment: Great thanks, I had noticed those p tags but I didn't know how to remove them.  I'll check out that article, thanks a lot.